# Set of Upper Bounds

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let *S* be a subset of the reals, and suppose that *S* is bounded above. Let *B* be the set of upper bounds of *S* and suppose that *B* has no lower bound. What do you conclude about *S*?

I know that it probably has something to do with the Completeness Axiom. I guessed that *S* is empty, because *B* basically "pushed" the upper bound of S lower and lower (because *B* is not bounded below). I tried to do this more formally: If *S* has an upper bound x where x ≥ y for all y in *S*, but there is a set *B* of zs where z gets smaller and smaller, there will always be a z in *B* such that z < x. So the set *S* is empty.

Comment: Every $s\in S$ serves as lower bound for $B$. So if $B$ has no lower bounds then $S$ must be empty.

Comment: If you have found one of out answers satisfying you should accept it or at least vote it up.

Answer (score 0):

If B has no lower bound then S does not have lowest upper bound,meaning that it does not have a supremum(least upper bound) thus it violates the Completeness axiom(if set has upper bound then it has lowest upper bound) thus the set S would be unbound above which is a contradiction meaning that set B must have an infinum or...

In another case if set S is an empty set then every number is a upper bound for it.Thus B would contain all real numbers,and would be equal to R and thusly B would not have a smallest member.

Answer (score 0):

Every $s\in S$ has the property that $s\le b$ for every $b\in B$. In other words: every $s\in S$ serves as a lower bound for $B$. If $B$ has no lower bounds then it follows immediately that $S=\emptyset$.